# Reading data from 2 textfields for each TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

As the title said; I want to read the data from multiple `UITextField`s for each cell and store them in an array. How would I do so?

I have created a subclass `CustomCell` that has 2 `UITextFields` in it. P/S: the identifier for the cell is also `CustomCell`

Many thanks

```
class TableViewController : UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
var data = [input]()

@IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as! CustomCell

    customCell.input1.tag = indexPath.row
    customCell.input2.tag = indexPath.row
    customCell.input1.delegate = self
    customCell.input2.delegate = self

    return customCell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

@IBAction func addButton(_ sender: Any) {
    table.beginUpdates()
    table.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: data.count-1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
    table.endUpdates()
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: textField.tag, section: 0)

    if let customCell = self.table.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell{

        let a = customCell.Credit.text!.isEmpty ? no:String(customCell.input1.text!)
        let b = customCell.letterGrade.text!.isEmpty ? no:String(customCell.input2.text!))

        inputRead.append(input(string1: a, string2: b))

    }

 @IBAction func foo(_ sender: Any) {
    if inputRead.count == 0{
        return
    }
    //the rest of implementation

}
```

CustomCell class:

```
Import UIKit

public class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var input1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var input2: UITextField!

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @Alan Bui..!! Share the code what you have tried so far. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: I just did. Not much going on yet :(

Comment: For that you have to implement textField delegates and create one array of strings to store textField text and whenever user type in textField store in array

Answer (score 1):

Update your code as follow in your view controller.

Assign textfield's delegate self to ViewController in `cellForRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {  
    let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    customCell.input1.delegate = self
    customCell.input2.delegate = self

    return customCell
}
```

Now implemented text field delegate in your view controller.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    guard let jobTaskCell = textField.superview?.superview as? CustomCell else {
        return
    }

    if textField == jobTaskCell.input1 {
        // Get text from textfield and store in array
    } else if textField == jobTaskCell.input2 {
        // Get text from textfield and store in array
    }
}
```

> **Note:** Following code depends on how to place textfield in your cell. So make sure you need to check this recursively by adding and removing **superView**
>
> ```
> guard let jobTaskCell = textField.superview?.superview as? CustomCell else {
>     return
> }
> ```
>
> This simply mean that, just for when textfield inside tableview cell without any extra view:
>
> **textField.superview = contentView of TableViewCell**
>
> **textField.superview?.superview = TableViewCell**

I hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: There is a problem on line "customCell.textField1.delegate = self" as "Cannot assign value of type 'TableViewController' to type 'UITextFieldDelegate?". How should I fix it?

Comment: @AlanBui fix it by adding `UITextFieldDelegate` to the `TableViewController`

Comment: Update your code `class TableViewController : UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate { ... }` will fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping!!

Comment: Sorry but it does not seem to work. I append them to my array but it does not seem appending at all. What could possibly be the case?

Answer (score 0):

**This can help you to store text in an array:-**

1: Add **indexPath.row as a tag to your textField in cellForRowAt**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {  

    let customCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    customCell.input1.tag = indexPath.row
    customCell.input2.tag = indexPath.row
    customCell.input1.delegate = self
    customCell.input2.delegate = self

    return customCell
}
```

2: In **textField delegate method you can get your textField text**

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: textField.tag, section: 0)

    if let customCell = self.table.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell {

        //From here you can get your particular input1 or input2 textfield text
         print(customCell.input1.text)
         print(customCell.input2.text)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for this question. I am new to app development. Can I call the delegate method inside an action button? In addition, would this method reads all the data from all the cell? I imagine the method would involve a for loop or something like that.

Comment: But it's not the proper way to call the delegate methods, and textFieldDidEndEditing textfield delegate method called when user stops typing and whole text will you get in textFieldt.text, Can you implement this answer?

Comment: I see. Another question that currently I am placing 2 TextFields in a same row( [input1] [input2]). Would this affect the code in cellForRowAt method?

Comment: oh wait nvm, sorry for a dumb question

Comment: how would I store input1 and input2 to the array I have? Is the row same as the index to my array? I did some research and since each of the cell I have only 1 row, so that the index of array should be the same with the IndexPath.section right?

Comment: Can you see my 2nd point in the answer you can get the text of both textField input1 and input2, you just want to create a string array and append it in if let where I wrote print statement

Comment: Would it be insufficient because everytime the addButton method is called, I append an empty cell to my data array?. Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: Why you are adding cell from clicking on a button, if you want to add a cell then add from cellForRowAt not from button action is not a proper way to add cell!

Comment: I think everytime I call addButton, it is better to have a global variable count to determine the next row for the cell to be added. What do you think?

Comment: Got it. Thank you

Comment: If you like it, you can upward my answer or suggestions , Thanks @AlanBui

Comment: I just did, I don't think it gets shown because my reputation is < 15

Comment: Sorry but it does not seem to work. I append them to my array but it does not seem appending at all. What could possibly be the case?

Comment: Can you upload your code to question, then i can tell you?

Comment: The foo button does not do anything resulted in inputRead.count is always 0

Comment: You want whenever user is going to type in input1 or input2 textfield it append on array, is this you want?

Comment: Yeah, same thing for other cell as well

Comment: Why you're created inputRead.append(input(string1: a, string2: b)) input model array and appending at a time user is going to type one textfield so one textfield text is going to append so you have to create string array for that then append just you have to check input1.resignFirstResponder then append it in the string array @AlanBui

Comment: inputRead is an array of input object. The reason that foo's implementation involves 2 variables in parallel.